# How to get the device name in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

How can I get my device name (using WinCE) in C# code ?

It gives me only "WindowsCE" how can i get the type on name of the device ? (ex. symbol or datalogic or mio...)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to retrieve the device name on Windows CE 5 using

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The registry value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Ident\Name contains the device name. Use the registry library to read it.

Answer (score 1):

What "Name" are you after?  If you're reading the registry entry indicated by FrozenFire and getting "WindowsCE" then that's what the OEM populated for the device name.  Is tehre some other name being reported by the device elsewhere with another value that you want?  If so, where are you seeing it and what is the value?  Are you maybe thinking about the device unique ID ([example posted by the WinMo team here](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2006/01/09/510997.aspx)).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Environment.MachineName
```

Comment: Are You try it on win ce platform or only write because on PC working? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx

Comment: Not available in Compact plaform please RTM before giving an answer!